# LinkedBlockingQueue's thread-safety with many producers in a producer-consumer scenario

Tags: java, concurrency, race-condition, producer-consumer, blockingqueue

I'm trying to model a situation in Java in which many producers (at least 2) access the same LinkedBlockingQueue at a fixed rate. They produce, put, and then start over again.
I was wondering whether this could eventually lead to race conditions between those producers which try to gain write access on the queue at the same time. Are java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue's implementations already set up to handle such an issue, or should I manually create mutexes in order to avoid this kind of problems?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: All BlockingQueues are thread safe.

Comment: "Note that a BlockingQueue can safely be used with multiple producers and multiple consumers." from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java's blocking queues are **thread-safe for single operations** such as take and put but **are not for multiple operations** of put or take operations such as addAll which is not being performed atomically.

so in your case the answer is no, you should not handle the thread-safety yourself unless you would like the producers to produce multiple products and put them all in one operation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is any starvation-avoidance mechanism also provided by default when accessing blocking queues for single operations?

Comment: May not help in your case, but ArrayBlockingQueue has a fairness flag that can be set in the constructor.  This guarantees that blocking operations are serviced in FIFO order, which can prevent starvation.